# Extra space, and Horizontal Scrollbar

Tags: css, layout, scrollbar

I cannot find what `CSS` is causing an abnormal ***space and scrollbar*** to appear as noted in the image below:

[image]

The website page is here:
http://www.ridgestyle.com/forum/

And the CSS page is here:
http://ridgestyle.com/forum/Themes/ridgestyle_2/css/index.css?fin20

I don't know where to start looking for the error. Any thoughts?

Comment: You should include the relevant code here; otherwise, it’s just a sort of "debug my website", which isn’t really a good fit for Stack Overflow. (See also: [FAQ])

Comment: Thanks for the question "reformat", arttronics.

Comment: @minitech  Understood. However, since I did not know which selector was the culprit, I guess it was sort of a 'debug' question (sorry). My hope was that someone with keen CSS eyes would have a minute to take a look; Which is what occurred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the padding: 5px; on the #bodyarea in CSS

Change

```
#bodyarea {
    padding: 5px;
    color: #444;
    background: #FEFEFE url(../images/img/bodyarea-bg.gif) 0 0 repeat-x;
}
```

to

```
#bodyarea {
    padding: 5px 0px;
    color: #444;
    background: #FEFEFE url(../images/img/bodyarea-bg.gif) 0 0 repeat-x;
}
```

It will remove the padding left and right but keep the top and bottom padding.

Also, html has min-height set to 101% which causes the scrollbar to appear when it's not necessary. ( on line 113 of the CSS file)

Comment: @ Gillian Thank-You. The padding is left over from the theme I was editing, and is not necessary at all. Removing it worked perfectly.

Comment: The 101% height is my approach to always force a vert. scrollbar for page consistency. Thx.